# Changing tool executable name in Xcode 4.6

Tags: xcode, macos

I've found several answers here which would seem to answer this question, none of them have worked.

I'm making a command line tool with Xcode 4.6.2, under Mac OS X 10.8.5. The tool started as a copy of the "USBNotificationExample". I can not find out how to change the product name, whatever I do its stubbornly "USBNotificationExample".

If I click on the product name in the project, the right pane has an edit box with the name "USBNotificationExample", but this is greyed out and can not be edited.

I have changed every other editable field I can find. The project name has been edited.

I have edited the build settings in the Packaging section. "Product Name" has been changed. (Initially this was blank, which seemed strange.)

I even tried directly editing the project.pbxproj inside the project package, that didn't work either.

Answer (score 4):

I am using Xcode 5, however I am certain this has not changed since Xcode 4.

What you want is *Packaging > Product Name* (filter on "name").

Below is an example of a product that started as "TestProject" but I renamed to "MyNewName"

[image]

Comment: As I mentioned, I already tried Packaging > Product Name and that didn't work.

Comment: @Barry That's the way it's done, unless you've messed-up the `Info.plist` file.

Comment: Agree to Droppy's answer. Note that in your 'Info.plist', as mentioned before, there are variables like ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} and ${PRODUCT_NAME} ... if you have changed any of these from the vanilla settings, you should revert that.